# Postgres: Large join optimisation

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, let's say

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_a BIGINT,
  a_b BIGINT,
  a_c BIGINT,
  a_someval NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  b_a BIGINT,
  b_b BIGINT,
  b_c BIGINT,
  b_someval NUMERIC
);
```

I'm joining them in the following way:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  JOIN b ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c)
;
```

Explain show, that planner needs to sort that tables on columns used in JOIN.

Is there a way to pre-sort these table so they will not be sorted each time they are joined?

Some things that may be important:

- the query uses whole content of both tables (not a small subset of rows)
- there are hundreds of millions of rows in each table
- content of tables will not be changing - both of these tables are generated (CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT ...) in the snapshot of the production database used for analytical needs

Comment: Did you create indices for these columns?

Comment: Yes, I've got them, but they are not used as query is joining whole tables.

Comment: How many rows do the tables have?  Sometimes, indices are not used when tables are very small.

Comment: In this case indices are not used since whole content of both tables is used anyway. There is no reason for planner to use indices.

Comment: Have you tried [clustering](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-cluster.html)? Since your tables are read only it may answer your question  about pre-sorting tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to ensure that the tables are essentially pre-`join`ed and sorted, you could create a [*materialized view*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html) of the `join`ed tables.

This would result in the *materialized view* already having the results of the two tables being `join`ed together and sorted in the order you choose. You can also create *indexes* on any of the fields, unlike with regular views.

The code would then be something like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ab_mat AS
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c);
```

One potential downside to this approach is that *materialized views* cannot be updated, so the information is not real time (this is why they offer such better performance -- they are essentially view snapshots that are persisted to disk). However, that is perfectly fine for many use cases.

To get the information updated, simply create a *cron job* that runs a `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` command periodically on the *materialized view* at the interval you need. This can range from being relatively aggressive (e.g. every 5 minutes), to relatively lax, e.g. daily or weekly.

Keep in mind that *materialized views* can in turn be joined to other tables and views to mix in real time information. I used a hybrid setup like this recently to greatly improve the speed of an extremely complex query, where only some of the data needed to be truly real time.

Also, note that *materialized views* are not available in versions prior to 9.3.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

You could elect to specify the order in the view, in which case it would default to that ordering, or you could leave it unordered, as I have above, and order it dynamically every time.

You would query the *materialized view* like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM ab_mat
-- optional ordering
order by a, b, c;
```

And this means it does not need to do any `join`s at all, since it's already done and saved.

Comment: You can set a trigger on insert/update/delete/truncate of the source tables to refresh the materialized view.  See e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NYKevin/9433376).  This is nice if the tables don't change very often but you need to select from the view all the time.

Comment: True. Would not work for my aforementioned case, but may potentially be an option for OP's.

Comment: This is still going to require that the same problematic query is run, though. It is essentially the same as rerunning the query and storing the result every time the materialised view needs to be refreshed. In the absence of incremental refresh, a PostgreSQL MV is just syntactic sugar to avoid truncating and repopulating a table.

Comment: No possibility to update is not a problem. If `a` and `b` would be materialized views  with `ORDER BY` organizing columns in the same order in both views, will than query joining them use order they are already in?

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Assuming you don't need real time data, it's still a huge win, since you can then only take the perf. hit every hour, day, etc. when you explicitly do the refresh, instead of every single time the query is run. I have used MVs just recently to net a huge performance gain.

Comment: @khampson Yes, but my point is that you might as well just create a table using a join between these two tables, right after they are created part of the snapshot of the production database. An MV itself would not make this query any more efficient.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Well, then you would have to truncate/drop and recreate the table each time instead of simply refreshing it via a simple *psql* cron job. If you want to say that's just syntactic sugar, I suppose so, but it's much easier, as syntactic sugar often is, so I'd still call it a win.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that a sort is required for this, but if so then the trick is to get a large working memory area. I would have expected a hash join to be honest.

You might consider whether it is possible to implement partitioning of the two tables, with both of the source tables partitioned on the same key definition. I'm not sure that PostgreSQL implements partition-wise joins similarly to Oracle, but if it does not then you can implement it manually with a query such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_part01
JOIN b_part01 ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c)
union all
SELECT *
FROM a_part02
JOIN b_part02 ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c)
union all
...
union all
SELECT *
FROM a_part0n
JOIN b_part0n ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c);
```

... or as a series of separate queries:

```
CREATE TABLE result
AS
SELECT *
FROM a_part01
JOIN b_part01 ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c);

...

INSERT INTO result
SELECT *
FROM a_part0n
JOIN b_part0n ON (a.a_a = b.b_a AND a.a_b = b.b_b AND a.a_c = b.b_c)
```

This allows the query to be completed with a much lower memory footprint.

With regard to presorting the table data, I'm not sure whether PostgreSQL respects an ORDER BY on an insert or table creation, but you can easily test it to find out. If so you can sort the tables but the database will not know that they are sorted. The practical implication, though, may just be that the join is more efficient because sorting data that is already sorted might be more efficient. I would say that it is definitely worth testing.

However you are still implementing a sort of the data, just in a different part of the overall operation.

Having indexes in place might actually help, if they cover all the columns of the tables. Again though creating the index requires a sort, so you're just doing the work elsewhere.